# Cascade Enum.reduce/3 and Map.update/4

Tags: elixir

In my quest to find a good solution for [List possible train routes on a given model railway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62738820/list-possible-train-routes-on-a-given-model-railway) I try to tackle this:

```
# This is the data I have.
#
trains = [:red_train, :blue_train]
train_stations = ["Station 1", "Station 2"]

# This stepping stone is calculated by a function.
#
stations_permutations = [
    ["Station 1", "Station 2"], 
    ["Station 2", "Station 1"]
]

# This should be the result.
#
possible_routes = 
    [
    %{
        end: %{blue_train: "Station 2", red_train: "Station 1"},
        start: %{blue_train: "Station 2", red_train: "Station 1"}
    },
    %{
        end: %{blue_train: "Station 1", red_train: "Station 2"},
        start: %{blue_train: "Station 1", red_train: "Station 2"}
    },
    %{
        end: %{blue_train: "Station 1", red_train: "Station 2"},
        start: %{blue_train: "Station 2", red_train: "Station 1"}
    },
    %{
        end: %{blue_train: "Station 2", red_train: "Station 1"},
        start: %{blue_train: "Station 1", red_train: "Station 2"}
    }
    ]
```

My problem: I want to write a function `list_routes/2` which has `trains` and `train_stations` as parameter. It should return with a list of maps (one `start` and one `end`) which represent all possible routes on the given model railway. I'm mentally stuck in OO Ruby land and can not figure out how to solve this in a functional way.

I want to run through all `station_permutations` and match them to the `trains`. Once for `start` and once for `end`.

In Ruby I would do that with a loop. In Elixir that doesn't work. I guess that `Enum.reduce` and `Map.update` is the way to go. But is it and how can I cascade those?

```
def station_permutations(_train_stations) do
  [
    ["Station 1", "Station 2"], 
    ["Station 2", "Station 1"]
  ]
end

@doc """
Returns a list of all possible routes.

## Examples
    iex> Trains.list_routes([:red_train, :blue_train], ["Station 1", "Station 2"])
    [
      %{
        end: %{blue_train: "Station 2", red_train: "Station 1"},
        start: %{blue_train: "Station 2", red_train: "Station 1"}
      },
      %{
        end: %{blue_train: "Station 1", red_train: "Station 2"},
        start: %{blue_train: "Station 1", red_train: "Station 2"}
      },
      %{
        end: %{blue_train: "Station 1", red_train: "Station 2"},
        start: %{blue_train: "Station 2", red_train: "Station 1"}
      },
      %{
        end: %{blue_train: "Station 2", red_train: "Station 1"},
        start: %{blue_train: "Station 1", red_train: "Station 2"}
      }
    ]
"""
def list_routes(trains, train_stations) do
  station_permutations(train_stations)
  |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn stations, acc ->
    Map.update(acc, stations, nil, ???????)
  end)
end
```

Comment: Do you always have only 2 trains and/or 2 stations passed to `Trains.list_routes` ?

Comment: Or maybe always the same number of trains and stations ?

Comment: No the number of trains and stations is not limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would compute all possible states of the trains:

```
possible_states = Enum.map(stations_permutations, &Enum.zip(trains, &1))
```

Then I would loop over those states, in a double loop, one for the starting state, the other for the ending state:

```
for state_start <- possible_states, state_end <- possible_states do
  %{start: state_start, end: state_end}
end
```

If you really want to use `reduce` for learning purposes then:

```
Enum.reduce(possible_states, [], fn state_start, acc ->
  Enum.reduce(possible_states, acc, fn state_end, acc ->
    [%{start: state_start, end: state_end} | acc]
  end)
end)
```

Note the initial accumulator for the outer loop is `[]` whereas the inner loop receives the current accumulator `acc`.